# How to Add new column with the sum of the other 2 column in datagridview?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hi how can i display the computed timeout and timein in a new column

say i have this column data in my data grid view :

```
Emplyee ID | EmployeeName | Date       | TimeIN | TimeOut
        0  | Danilo       | 2013-06-06 | 08:00  | 15:00
```

then i want to display the result like this :

```
Emplyee ID | EmployeeName | Date       | TimeIN | TimeOut | TOTAL
        0  | Danilo       | 2013-06-06 | 08:00  | 15:00   | 7:00
```

i have try this code :

```
    Dim sDateFrom As TimeSpan
    Dim sDateTo As TimeSpan
    Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = lblholdname.Text Then

            sDateFrom = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            sDateTo = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value

            timeDiff = sDateTo - sDateFrom

'this code is not right i want column instead of row but its not accepting timespan
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = timeDiff
'i try using this too 
'DataGridView1.Columns.Add("TOTAL", "TOTAL") = timeDiff


        End If

    Next
```

ok so i manage to get what i need but a new problem come instead of displaying 1 column its displaying 2 column my table now looks like this

```
Emplyee ID | EmployeeName | Date       | TimeIN | TimeOut | TOTAL | TOTAL
        0  | Danilo       | 2013-06-06 | 08:00  | 15:00   | 7:00  |
```

and i add this code to get that result :

```
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("TOTAL", "TOTAL")

            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = timeDiff
```

ok this is how i populate my DGV with DATA in my database :

```
con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;username=root;password=nhhs;port=3306;database=employeedb"
    con.Open()
    cmd = New MySqlCommand("select e.employeeID, e.employeefname, e.employeelname, t.dateoftime, t.timein,t.timeout from tblemployee as e, tbltimepunch as t where e.employeelname = '" & lblholdlastname.Text & _
                           "' and e.employeeID = t.employeeID and dateoftime between '" & MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & _
                           "' and '" & MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'", con)

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    With DataGridView1
        .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "employeeID"
        .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "employeefname"
        .Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "employeelname"
        .Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "dateoftime"
        .Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "timein"
        .Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "timeout"
        .DataSource = dt
    End With
    con.Close()
```

Comment: How are you filling your datagrid? Is it data bound?

Comment: yeah my datagridview load the data in my database i somehow manage to do what i want but my next problem is it add 2 column instead of 1

Comment: Please post the code how do you bind grid-view currently. Do you populate using DataSet or DataTable?

Comment: im using data table..ok wait a minute ill edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a DataTable with all columns you need at the DAL or BL level (however you are using it) for the GridView instead of manipulating the Grid structure at UI level.

```
Public Function DataTable1() as DataTable
      con = New MySqlConnection
      con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;username=root;password=nhhs;port=3306;database=employeedb"
      con.Open()
      cmd = New MySqlCommand("select e.employeeID, e.employeefname, e.employeelname, t.dateoftime, t.timein,t.timeout from tblemployee as e, tbltimepunch as t where e.employeelname = '" & lblholdlastname.Text & _
                                   "' and e.employeeID = t.employeeID and dateoftime between '" & MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & _
                                   "' and '" & MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'", con)

       da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
       dt = New DataTable
       da.Fill(dt)

       return dt
End Function
```

Create new DataTable and manually generate columns as you need. This is where you will create the column that adds whichever columns you want to add.

```
Public Shared Function DataTable2(byval table as DataTable) As DataTable
         Dim tbl As New DataTable()
         tbl.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
         tbl.Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(String))
         tbl.Columns.Add("Col3", GetType(String))
         For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
               tbl.Rows.Add(New Object() {[String].Format("Col1{0}", row.Item("column1")), [String].Format("Col2{0}", row.Item("column2")), [String].Format("Col3{0}", row.Item("column1") + row.Item("column2"))})
        Next row

    return tbl;
End Function
```

And just bind this object to the Gridview.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable2(DataTable1);
```

You will need to modify and format the code as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalColum = new DataGridViewColumn();
totalColum.Name = "Missing Time";
totalColum.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
dataGridView2.Columns.Insert(index, totalColum);
```